# Auto restart gulp nodejs on exception

Tags: node.js, gulp, forever, nodemon

I have a nodejs app running with a gulp script. This gulp is started with forever.

```
forever start gulp
```

When any exception is thrown, it just gets freezed with below error msg.

```
[gulp] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here for this exception I know that there is no file change required, it was just caused by some connection timeout event.

So, its a forever + gulp + nodejs

Can we automatically restart this gulp script on any exception? Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

**Update 1:**

Gulp script

```
var fs            = require('fs'),
    path          = require('path'),
    gulp          = require('gulp'),
    gutil         = require('gulp-util'),
    es            = require('event-stream'),
    concat        = require('gulp-concat'),
    runSequence   = require('gulp-run-sequence'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    minifyHtml    = require('gulp-minify-html'),
    ngmin         = require('gulp-ngmin'),
    less          = require('gulp-less'),
    rimraf        = require('gulp-rimraf'),
    jshint        = require('gulp-jshint'),
    stylish       = require('jshint-stylish'),
    uglify        = require('gulp-uglify'),
    minifyCss     = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    gulpif        = require('gulp-if'),
    nodemon       = require('gulp-nodemon'),
    _             = require('lodash'),
    moment        = require('moment'),
    shell         = require('gulp-shell'),
    minimist      = require('minimist'),
    rename        = require('gulp-rename');

var BASE        = 'src/client/app',
    ASSETS_BASE = 'src/client/assets'

var appFiles      = applyPrefix(BASE,        ['/entry/app.js', '/**/*.js']),
    templateFiles = applyPrefix(BASE,        ['/**/*.html']),
    lessFiles     = applyPrefix(BASE,        ['/entry/less/main.less', '/**/*.less']),
    adminLess     = applyPrefix(BASE,        ['/entry/less/admin.less']),
    libFiles      = applyPrefix(ASSETS_BASE, ['/js/lib/jquery.min.js', '/js/lib/lodash.min.js', '/js/lib/angular.min.js', '/js/lib/**/*.js', '/js/components/**/*.js']),
    assetFiles    = applyPrefix(ASSETS_BASE, ['/fonts/**/*', '/img/**/*', '/translations/**/*', '/favicon.ico']),
    viewsFiles    = applyPrefix(BASE,        ['/entry/views/*.html']);

var compile = gutil.env.compile;

gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
  runSequence(
    'clean',
    ['scripts', 'assets', 'less', 'adminLess', 'views'],
    'watch',
    cb
  );
});

gulp.task('clean', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/server/public', { read: false })
           .pipe(rimraf());
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    gulp.src(['src/server/public/js/*main.js', 'src/server/public/js/*lib.js', 'src/server/public/js/*templates.js'], { read: false })
      .pipe(rimraf());

    var buildTimestamp = moment().format("MM-D-YYYY-HH:mm:ss");

    fs.writeFile('src/server/js-build-timestamp.json', JSON.stringify({ buildTimestamp: buildTimestamp }), function(err) {
      if (err) return console.log("Could not create js-build-timestamp file");
      console.log("Created js-build-timestamp file: " + buildTimestamp);
    });

    // App files
    gulp.src(appFiles)
      .pipe(jshint({
        strict: false,
        laxbreak: true,
        debug: true,
        globals: {
          angular: true,
          $: true,
          _: true
        }
    }))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish))
    .pipe(concat(buildTimestamp + '-main.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, ngmin()))
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/public/js'));

  // Template files
  gulp.src(templateFiles)
    .pipe(minifyHtml({
      empty: true,
      spare: true,
      quotes: true
    }))
    .pipe(templateCache({
      module: 'xxxProjName',
      root: '',
      base: function(file) {
        return 'templates/' + path.basename(file.relative);
      }
    }))
    .pipe(concat(buildTimestamp + '-templates.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, ngmin()))
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, uglify()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/public/js'));

  // Library files
  gulp.src(libFiles)
    .pipe(concat(buildTimestamp + '-lib.js'))
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, uglify({
      preserveComments: 'some'
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/public/js'));
});

gulp.task('less', function() {
  gulp.src(['src/server/public/css/*.css'], { read: false })
    .pipe(rimraf());

  var buildTimestamp = moment().format("MM-D-YYYY-HH:mm:ss");
  fs.writeFile('src/server/css-build-timestamp.json', JSON.stringify({ buildTimestamp: buildTimestamp }), function(err) {
    if (err) return console.log("Could not create css-build-timestamp file");
    console.log("Created css-build-timestamp file: " + buildTimestamp);
  });

  gulp.src(lessFiles[0])
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename(buildTimestamp + '-main.css'))
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/public/css'));
});

gulp.task('adminLess', function() {
  gulp.src(adminLess)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulpif(compile, minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/public/css'));
});

gulp.task('assets', function() {
  gulp.src(assetFiles, { base: ASSETS_BASE})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/public/'));
});

gulp.task('views', function() {
  gulp.src(viewsFiles)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/server/views/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  if (compile) return;

  gulp.watch([appFiles, templateFiles, libFiles], ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(['client/index.html', assetFiles], ['assets']);
  gulp.watch([lessFiles], ['less', 'adminLess']);
  gulp.watch([viewsFiles], ['views']);

  nodemon({
    script: 'src/server/server.js',
    watch: 'src/server',
    ext: 'json js',
    ignore: ['client/*, src/server/public/*']
  });
});

function applyPrefix(prefix, fileNames) {
  return _.map(fileNames, function(fileName) {
    return prefix + fileName;
  });
}


gulp.task('bleh', function() {
  gulp.src('')
    .pipe(shell([
      'touch test'
    ]))
});
```

Comment: There also seems to be nodemon involved. Could you post the gulp script?

Comment: @ZeMoon - I have updated with gulp script

Answer (score 1):

Install nodemon globally `npm i -g nodemon`

And add in your .bashrc (or .bash_profile or .profile) an alias
`alias gulp='nodemon --watch gulpfile.js --watch gulpfile.babel.js --quiet --exec gulp'`

This will watch for file gulpfile.js and gulpfile.babel.js (see [Google](https://www.google.am/#q=gulpfile.babel.js)) changes

**p.s. this can be helpful for endless tasks (like watch, ...) but not for single run tasks. I mean it uses watch so it will continue process even after gulp task is done. ;)
p.s.2. nodemon has flag to exit on crash it's `--exitcrash`. so don't include it :)**